# Whose superhero-themed shoes are the shoes shown in the S01E05 end credits?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, she-hulk-attorney-at-law

In *She-Hulk: Attorney at Law* S01E05 "Mean, Green, and Straight Poured into These Jeans", Pug is looking to buy the new "Iron Man Three" shoes. In the end credits, Pug is showing (what is presumably) the Iron Man Three shoes to Nikki (probably from his shoe collection) and several Marvel superhero (or supervillain)-themed shoes are shown in the background.

**Which superhero (or supervillain) is associated with each shoe?**

Screencap:
[image: screencap of scene described above]

Relevant dialogue:

> **Pug:** Will you stand in line with me waiting for a sneaker drop?
> The Iron Man Threes are coming out. They're limited to one pair per customer.
> […]
> **Pug:** I'm not gonna brag to you or anything, but I do have some pretty rare limited editions that I got from my drip broker.

Answer (score 8):

Kicking off a Community answer. Feel free to edit in any more answers that you can identify.

[image: (image annotated with coordinates)]

### B

- B6 - Moon Knight

### C

- C6 - Spider-Man
- C7 - Black Panther

### D

- D5 - Electro
- D6 - Captain Marvel
- D7 - Cyclops

### E

- E3 - Iron Man
- E5 - Namor
- E7 - Classic Vision

### F

- F3 - Ghost Rider
- F4 - Nova
- F7 - Thing
- F9 - Deadpool

### G

- G2 - Juggernaut
- G3 - Doctor Strange
- G4 - Falcon
- G5 - Hulk
- G9 - Captain America

### H

- H4 - The Invisible Woman

Comment: H6 might be the old Hawkeye costume.  G8 makes me think of Judge Dredd.

Comment: I've seen on another site that one of them is meant to be vision, but I don't know which one

Comment: Two of them come to mind depending on whether we're talking about the white Vision (H7), or the red and green one from the comics (E7).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Booster Gold is a DC character.

Comment: G6 resembles (the Fabulous) Frogman. He seems like an odd inclusion, though.

Comment: @LogicDictates: I mean, he is supposed to be on the show according to the trailers...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Got a link? That sounds very odd.

Comment: @LogicDictates: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mInfRhVLzI4

Comment: And @1:07 in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrTnNN4VooQ

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Darn pronouns. I thought you were talking about Booster Gold, not Frogman. :-)

Comment: Oh, you're right. It just looked like such a match. :-D

Comment: This all seems like complete guesswork

Comment: Points for Invisible Woman. I bet they were the most expensive ones.

Comment: "*The Invisible Woman*" I didn't see what you did there…

Comment: Why no "A" row?